Drawing a dash line on swift
I managed to create a function called dash_line in swift to create dash line between 2 points:
    context_dash.setStrokeColor(color!.cgColor)
    context_dash.setLineWidth(strokeWidth)
    
    let dashArray:[CGFloat] = [d1,d2,d3,d4]
    context_dash.setLineDash(phase: strokeWidth, lengths: dashArray)
    context_dash.move(to: CGPoint(x: p1.x, y: p1.y))
    context_dash.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: p2.x, y: p2.y))

    context_dash.drawPath(using: CGPathDrawingMode.stroke)

If I call first this function dash_Line, I can see a dash line between pointA and pointB, but all lines created by another function called continuous_Line became dash line.
This is happening only if I call dash_Line function first.
But if I called the continuous_Line first, all the line created by this function aer continuous.
What codes I need to add in the dash_Line function in order not to affect the other functions.

You need to provide your full function definition. Cocoa drawing uses a graphics "context". Unless you set your drawing context first, you affect the global drawing context. That's almost certainly what's going on, but you need to show all of your dashed_line function.

Also, how are you doing drawing? And is this iOS or Mac OS? Do you have a UIView/NSView that overrides the draw(rect:) method? And are you calling your dashed_line function from draw(rect:)? We need more information.

Surround every batch of code that configures your context with save and restore calls, like this:
context_dash.saveGState()
let dashArray:[CGFloat] = [d1,d2,d3,d4]
context_dash.setLineDash(phase: strokeWidth, lengths: dashArray)
context_dash.move(to: CGPoint(x: p1.x, y: p1.y))
context_dash.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: p2.x, y: p2.y))
context_dash.restoreGState()


You are just awesome @matt, Thank you very much, it works perfectly.

You can try this:
func dash_Line(context_dash: CGContext?, color: UIColor?, strokeWidth: CGFloat, d1: CGFloat, d2: CGFloat, d3: CGFloat, d4: CGFloat, p1: CGPoint, p2: CGPoint) {
guard let context_dash = context_dash else {
    return
}

context_dash.setStrokeColor(color!.cgColor)
context_dash.setLineWidth(strokeWidth)

let dashArray:[CGFloat] = [d1,d2,d3,d4]
context_dash.setLineDash(phase: strokeWidth, lengths: dashArray)
context_dash.move(to: CGPoint(x: p1.x, y: p1.y))
context_dash.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: p2.x, y: p2.y))
context_dash.drawPath(using: CGPathDrawingMode.stroke)

// Reset line dash pattern to default
context_dash.setLineDash(phase: 0, lengths: [])

}
